# How can I convert from an E11 socket to an E26 socket?

Tags: electrical

Our church has halogen light fixtures with E11 sockets. We would like to convert these fixtures to accept E26 bulbs.

I am unable to find a direct adapter, is there any other way I can convert these sockets to E26, and are there any issues in doing so?

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/) might come in handy here, or you could try your local hardware store.

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure that no one makes such an adapter, it would be a risky proposition for a manufacturer for these reasons:

1. The mechanical stresses on the socket would be too great.  The adaptor would be too prone to breaking or to destroying the socket.  For an idea about why too much mass is not good for too small a socket, Pick up a full, 2-liter soda bottle only by the cap and try to hold it horizontally.
2. Many (but not all) E11 sockets are only rated for 50 watts or less.  The temptation to use a 60-watt, or larger bulb, in an E26 socket would be too great -- a big fire risk.

The largest E11 upsizing adapter I've seen is [an E11 to E17](http://samlighting.com/catalogue/auxiliary-parts/converter-adapter#E11).

**The smart thing to do would be to replace the fixtures or continue to use only E11 bulbs.**

But, if you really want to earn your spot on [the Redneck Repairs Blog](http://thereifixedit.failblog.org/), you could use two adapters:  The E11 to E17 and then [an E17 to E26](http://samlighting.com/catalogue/auxiliary-parts/converter-adapter#E17) (NOT recommended).

[image: Don't do this]